Why is my SFML + OpenGL application rendering a 3D model with transparency, even after disabling blending and setting opaque colors?
I'm developing a game engine using SFML for window management and OpenGL for rendering with C++. My goal is to render a 3D model, but parts of the model appear transparent. I've tried multiple approaches to ensure the model is rendered fully opaque, but the issue persists. As i rotate my camera around the model, the front faces are invisible. Due to this i always see the faces in the back.



My setup (minimal):
SFML Window Initialization
sf::ContextSettings settings;
settings.depthBits = 24;
settings.stencilBits = 8;
settings.antialiasingLevel = 0;
settings.majorVersion = 3;
settings.minorVersion = 3;

sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML + OpenGL", sf::Style::Default, settings);
window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
glDisable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);

Game Loop
while (m_isRunning) {
    handleEvents();

    // Clear the screen
    glClearColor(0.9f, 0.9f, 1.0f, 1.0f); // Opaque light blue background
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Update logic
    m_activeScene->update(deltaTime);

    // Render logic
    window.pushGLStates();
    m_activeScene->render(); // Custom rendering
    window.popGLStates();

    window.display();
}

Model Shader (for fragment shading the model):
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 TexCoords;

uniform sampler2D texture_diffuse1;

void main() {
    vec4 texColor = texture(texture_diffuse1, TexCoords);
    FragColor = vec4(texColor.rgb, 1.0); // Force full opacity
}


What I've Tried

I disabled blending globally before rendering
glDisable(GL_BLEND);


I ensured the clear color has a fully opaque alpha value
glClearColor(0.9f, 0.9f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


I ensured depth testing is enabled
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);


I replaced the fragment shader with a simple solid color to isolate texture issues. The model still renders with transparency in some areas.


Questions:

Why is the model rendering with transparency, even after disabling blending and ensuring opaque colors in the shader?

Could the issue be related to the default framebuffer's alpha channel? If so, how can I render fully opaque objects?

Are there other OpenGL states or configurations that could cause this behavior when rendering 3D models?



Any insights or suggestions?

This looks like a model loading problem. Please provide code that you use to build the model geometry and preferably make it a minimal working example

At first glance, I'd guess that this is either a model loading problem or a depth buffer issue. Does it work when you just render a cube?

What happens when you try different input for glDepthFunc(GL_LESS)?
